# Google Drive files in Google search result

Tags: google-drive, google-search

But even being publicly available, our files will not show up in a Google search right? I would like them to show up. Or we have to publish that Google Drive link in some webpage describing the files, so they can be actually reached thru Google search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get your google drive files in google search,
then you need to paste your share(public) links in sites like pastebin or blogger.

After few days it will definitely show up in google search.